# Como funciona esse algoritimo de buscar o menor valor de um array?

Tags: python, algoritmo

estou iniciando os estudos e estou estudando o livro entendo os algoritmos e no cap 2 não entendi esse algoritmo.

Aqui no caso é para encontrar o menor valor de um elemento.

```
def buscaMenor(arr):
    menor = arr[0]
    menor_indice = 0
    for i in range(1, len(arr)):
        if arr[i] < menor:
            menor = arr[i]
            menor_indice = i
        return menor_indice  
    
def ordenacaoporselecao(arr):
    novoArr = []
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        menor = buscaMenor(arr)
        novoArr.append(arr.pop(menor))
    return novoArr

print ordenacaoporselecao([5, 3, 6, 2, 10])
```

aqui no meu entendimento pensei que iria ordenar os itens.

poderiam me ajudar a entender esses códigos e se tem dicas ou sugestões para aprender os algoritmos ?

Answer (score 0):

Sim, o algoritmo está ordenando o array. A lógica é:

- Função ordenacaoporselecao possui um for que percorre cada posição do array original;
- Para cada posição é chamada a função buscaMenor que busca o menor elemento;
- O menor elemento é inserido no novo array e removido no array original;
- A função ordenacaoporselecao retorna o novo array ordenado.

Para você entender isso de forma mais clara, você pode ir adicionando comentários exibindo o valor de cada varável ou simplesmente debugando o código.

Comment: Obrigado, pensei que quando desse o print ele iria ordenar do menor para o maior